# Could not find nokogiri in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, nokogiri, passenger

I've already read a dozen of installation problems with nokogiri gem here, but did not find how to resolve mine.

Gem installing proceeds without problems: `Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.3.1`.

But when I trying to open my rails app it says that:

`Could not find nokogiri-1.6.3.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`.

I've tried to install an older version 1.6.1 assuming that it could be more compatible, but in that case passenger (I use nginx passenger on Ubuntu 14.04 x64) says that can't find `mini_portile 0.5.3` which is nokogiri depends on. What's going on there?

Comment: are you using any gemset, there could be an issue with ruby version. check for ruby -v inside your application. check $gem list for the available gems inside that app

Comment: What ruby version are you using? If it's 1.8.7 make sure you have `require 'rubygems'` before any other gem requires

Comment: provide output for `cat $(which bundle) |head`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Putting this in the Gemfile works for me:

```
gem 'right_http_connection', git: 'git://github.com/rightscale/right_http_connection.git', ref: '3359524d81'
```

Seen on  [Ruby 2 Upgrade Breaks Nokogiri and/or open-uri Encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664261/ruby-2-upgrade-breaks-nokogiri-and-or-open-uri-encoding) :

> Ok, here's an answer, and maybe the answer. Ruby 2 changed how it uses
>   headers in HTTP requests and zipping/deflating, but at some point they
>   changed their minds back and put it to be how 1.9 worked. In the
>   interim some Rails gem maintainers monkey patched HTTP:Net to make
>   their gems work on both 1.9 and 2.0. Those monkey patches still linger
>   in older versions of gems and cause issues like I saw upgrading from
>   1.9 to 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Deploying app sources to another folder fixed this problem.